# Is there Ubuntu Unstable/Development, like Debian Sid (Unstable)?

Tags: release-management

I'd like to install such Ubuntu that it has always most recent APT packages. For example if new CLang is released then I want to have it in my Ubuntu in one or two weeks.

Is there anything in Ubuntu like Unstable or Development version (same like Debian's Sid) that updates APT packages very often?

Also very important - how can I install it? Where to download? I see on [this page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) download links to versions 20 and 21 but both are not Unstable/Development versions as I understand.

Basically all I really want is just a web link for downloading some magical Development/Unstable Ubuntu as `.iso` file that I can install on my PC.

Comment: Be aware that having latest package versions is not the purpose of this distro. *In a way* non-LTS releases are themselves made for testing purposes, that is in view of the future LTS, which are indeed the flagships of Ubuntu and characterize its purpose. Unless you are a developer, you get into a contradiction by getting what you ask: Ubuntu is not meant for that.

Comment: @cipricus Yes, I'm a developer. Basically I need very often most recent apt packages. I usually was using `master` branches of all github projects instead of theirs releases, so I got used to this. If all apt packages will contain even just master-branches snapshots of all projects even then it is alright for me. If something is not working in one of projects I don't mind waiting a week or so till new APT update will get new fixed snapshot of that project. The only thing I need is that when some project is broken and is fixed in few days then I expect Ubuntu dev to update this apt in a week.

Comment: If you want the latest CLang in Ubuntu, build it yourself.  I've done (the equivalent to) that for years with Debian Sid and XEmacs (perennial) beta.

Comment: @gboffi I just mentioned CLang just for example of one of APT packages. Actually I need hundreds of different apt packages, to be updated often, not just CLang.

Comment: Two thoughts - Rolling Rhino as per N0rbert's answer, or you can use any release and have -proposed enabled.. though unless using the *development* release it's not quite the same (currently that's *impish*)...   I prefer the *development* release (currently *impish*) just like I like *testing* in Debian.  My using *impish* just means I need to *bump* my releases once every 6 months (usually about 30 hours post-release)

Comment: I don't understand your reference to 20 & 21.  Ubuntu uses *yy* format releases for *snap* only releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 20, which is a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).  Currently dailies are available for the *development* release (*impish* or what will be 21.10 on release; installs update normally and will become 21.10) or *focal* (what will be 20.04.3 when it's released).

Answer (score 9):

You can try great tool from Martin Wimpress.

The tool is named `rolling-rhino` and placed at [GitHub](https://github.com/wimpysworld/rolling-rhino):

> Rolling Rhino is a simple tool to convert Ubuntu Desktop, and the official
> desktop flavours, that has been installed from a daily image into a
> *"rolling release"* by opting into and tracking the `devel` series.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, I'll try this today! Can you please tell if I installed ISO [from here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/), do I have to use this rolling-rhino tool that you suggest? If I don't use the tool what about my APT packages, do I get all newest packages after doing `apt update`? And if I use this tool what will be the difference, will I get even more newer apt packages compared to not using tool?

Comment: Yesterday installed Ubuntu daily live [from here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) and today applied your suggested rolling-rhino script. It did something successfully. Can you please clarify what it actually did? How my daily-live distro that I installed yesterday how it is different to what it became after applying rolling-rhino? When I launched computer today my regular daily-live updated dozen of packages, so it means this dozen got into repo just today, it means that daily-live updates APT every day. So then what rolling rhino does, it also updates every day?

Comment: It will stay rolling after stabilization of Impish, thus you can jump to next version JJ flawlessly.

Comment: So it means until Impish is stabilized and becomes Release until this both daily-live Impish and rolling-rhino patched Impish will be both about the same?

Comment: Seems yes, right, @Arty.

Answer (score 8):

There is no 'rolling' development version like Sid is.

You will need to keep upgrading/installing the in-development releases (right now it's Impish 21.10) during the dev cycles to get the 'latest development' track.  There's no singular name like `sid` or Unstable in Debian to constantly track 'development'.

However, there is no 'magical' way to *continue* to track the development or unstable branches after a release is complete - except to 'upgrade' to the development release via `do-release-upgrade -d` on that system.  However, that isn't guaranteed to work, so you'd have to do a reinstall with the ISOs for that development release to *guarantee* you're on that devel track, and repeat the same behavior every time a new release is being developed.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell if I install current 21th ISO then to update apt packages I just do apt update+upgrade? And that's it? Thus I can update to recent-most packages every week?

Comment: @Arty that's correct, except that when that version of Ubuntu releases, you'll need to do a `do-release-upgrade -d` to the 22.04 development release when that's available, or a clean-install with the 22.04 isos.

Comment: Can you tell how often remote apt packages are updated in this live version? For example if new CLang or LLVM is released today, how many weeks after it will get to my PC apt? Are packages updated every week or at specific dates (like 1st of January and 1st of June)?

Comment: @Arty Impossible to specify, because development 'happens' - packages can get updated at any time, just like in Sid.  There's no specific dates for 'when packages will be available for you if you track the in-development release'.  So we can't guarantee you an update schedule.  There's a whole slew of testing of packages that have to happen first, it's entirely possible that an LLVM update could go out tomorrow or three days from now or three weeks from now, or possibly never.  If you just use the standard upgrade commands, you'll be fine.  Can't guarantee any dates for anything though.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of....

Most Ubuntu deb packages merge from Debian Testing (there are exceptions) twice each year, so there is no equivalent of Sid/Unstable.

Ubuntu is a distro that is designed for easy install and safe use by non-experts and beginners. It would be foolhardy to tempt (mislead) those users with a pre-release link on the main download page.

However, pre-release images DO exist -- any search engine will lead you to them at  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/. Try it.

As with Debian Testing, be aware that there are still rough edges -- that's why it's PRE-release. We encourage users with the skills to properly report bugs to test their workflows and hardware and favorite applications, and to file bugs so we can get those fixed before release. Bug reports with patches are even more welcome.

- AskUbuntu does NOT provide support for pre-release versions of Ubuntu.

Understanding the six-month-long development cycle of Ubuntu is a prerequisite for safe use of pre-release versions. If you don't intend to do proper testing (and file bugs), then pre-release may not be for you.

Comment: This daily-live version adds new packages every day? So if I do apt update+upgrade then I get recent-most packages, not just security updates? If new clang is released then after apt update I can download it too?

Comment: The way your follow-up comment is phrased suggests that a pre-release version may not currently be a good fit for you. You have not researched the six-month development life cycle, and understanding that is a prerequisite for safe use of pre-release versions of Ubuntu. Ask a Search Engine -- the cycle has been well-documented for over 15 years.

Answer (score 2):

You can download version 21.10 which is currently under development [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).

Comment: If I install it how then I upgrade my packages every week? Just through apt update+upgrade?

Comment: Just update following the usual procedure with apt or builtin autoupdater.

Comment: Can you tell how often remote apt packages are updated in this live version? For example if new CLang or LLVM is released today, how many weeks after it will get to my PC apt? Are packages updated every week or at specific dates (like 1st of January and 1st of June)?

Comment: Sorry, no, I can't tell you..